# Missing Visual Studio Android emulators from Cordova project targets

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, android-emulator

The last time I updated visual studio, I accidentally unchecked 'Android emulators' from the modules list, so they all got uninstalled. 
Since I need them, I went and modified the installation from windows 'add or remove programs', checked and installed 'Android emulators' as a visual studio module, and all seemed fine.

But then, when I tried to build an Android version of my Apache Cordova app, I noticed that the Android emulators did not get added back to the target list. The Cordova project is set as a start up project.

I tried reinstalling the whole module and also reinstalling the device profiles, but they're still missing.

Is there a way to configure what devices/emulators show in that list?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: ` Troubleshooting the Visual Studio Emulator for Android `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx

Comment: I have read that page before posting the question, but have not found anything helpful there. Is it something specific that you're referring to to?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like you are missing the Visual Studio emulators for Android, which we have pre configured to show a 5" and 7" option. A fresh install probably just missed that component (because its not automatically checked). Modify "Microsoft Visual Studio" from the Add or Remove programs menu, and check the VS Emulators for Android to add them to your version of VS. See the checklist image below for where the component is.

[image]

If you want to create a custom Android emulator yourself to show under "Google Android Emulator" (because that comes pre-installed), just make sure that your Google Android emulator is running the virtual device that you created, and on deploy your app should show up on that emulator.

Comment: That's why I included Emulator manager window in the screenshot, so it can be seen that I actually have the VS Android emulators installed. I can run the emulators just fine and, as I have later discovered, I can even deploy apps on them with the "Device" option selected from the dropdown menu. The issue is that I can't directly selected one of the VS studio emulators, and if I have a real android phone connected to the PC (which I have 90% of the time), Visual studio will build the android application and install it on the actual device, instead of the emulator.